# .htpasswd under IIS - does it work?

Tags: iis, .htaccess

I'm trying to password protect a directory on a server that's running IIS.

I've put the following in the .htaccess file in that directory -
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /path/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user

I've tried a whole bunch of different paths and although it's asking for a username and password it won't take it. I've tried using the path provided by _SERVER["PATH_TRANSLATED"] but that's no help either.

Is this a problem with my path, or does IIS just not support .htpasswd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS does not support .htpasswd or .htaccess.

Answer (score 3):

Helicon Ape (http://www.helicontech.com/ape naturally supports .htpasswd file with all these authentication options you’ve mentioned. The software also implements a bunch of other Apache-like features. As regarding authentication, you may also be interesting in these articles: http://helicontech.blogspot.com/search/label/mod_auth

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Natively IIS does not support the htpasswd.

You can get IISPassword for IIS from [here](http://www.iistools.com/) if you really want to use 
similar files under IIS.

Comment: IISPassword isn't supported on IIS7 at the moment.